# Data storage for Ruby? Marshal seems too memory intensive and slow

Tags: ruby, database

I'm loading ~500MB of Marshal'ed data into my program (the data is class instances consisting of nested arrays of strings, integers, and other classes) and:

1. it takes ages to do so.
2. my memory usage on my computer spikes to multiple GB.

Is there a better alternative for storing large amounts of data? Would SQL be better or is that just better for performing tasks on that data?

Comment: The Marshal format is dependent on the Ruby version so it is pretty much useless for persisting data, Marshal is only really useful for deep cloning and temporary serialization. Use a database of some sort, push your data management and querying logic into the database, and only load the data you need into Ruby.

Comment: What kind of data do you load? Where is it coming from? What do you do with that data in your app? Do you need to load all data at once?

Comment: Ruby has many different ways to store data or send/retrieve data to databases or other data repositories. You haven't told us enough about your needs to recommend anything better, besides, doing so is off-topic. You need to research the topic and try additional things, then when you run into a problem ask a specific question about it. Please read "[ask]", especially the parts about broad questions and questions that aren't well defined.

Comment: SQLite sounds like a better deal than "load in the universe and hope for the best". If your data isn't going to fit into a relational database you have other options as well. It really depends on the type of data you're dealing with.

Comment: tadman - fair enough. I just updated my original post but the data is in the form of class instances... that's why I originally decided on Mashal since I could just serialize them directly. Do you know of any gem that allows of easy conversion to SQL?

Comment: "If your data isn't going to fit into a relational database..." then you have a real problem because RDBMS can hold a HUGE amount of data. "Do you know of any gem..." is off-topic. I'd recommend searching for "ruby orm" and looking through the results. There are some that are used much more often but, again, we don't know your needs as well as you, so you'll have to do the research and pick something.